# Few errors while apt-get upgrade and apt-get install?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

When i try to install `libgl1-mesa-dev` and 
`libsdl1.2-dev`, I get the following error

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed 
Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed 
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

and:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
The following packages have been kept back:
libgbm1 libosmesa6:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install libcheese first. Then try this one.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)